# Are there required standards for gate power cable maintenance?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, electrical-system

I am looking for reference(s) addressing gate power cable maintenance, for both 28V DC and 400Hz. Do the FAA or any manufacturers have standards for measuring the connector pins to determine wear?

Comment: What would be the purpose of such a measurement? Is it a safety concern?

Comment: An undersized connector pin can cause electrical impulses on the aircraft structure. This in turn can damage LRUs. In extreme cases, it can place 115 Volts, 400-Hz on the structure. The same type of pin wear can occur on the aircraft ground power connector.

Comment: To answer your direct question, yes, I believe it's a major concern. Electrical noise can degrade Analog-yo-Digital (A/D) circuits used in sensors to convert analog signals to digital words the flight control system can process.

Comment: DC LRUs aren't going to be affected by bus power noise, as their input voltage is typically designed to handle 10-32 VDC. Any sensors are going to have their own power regulation as well, so I don't think that's a concern either.

Comment: Sorry, but very respectfully, you're wrong. All LRUs are bonded by the mounting trays, to the structure. Within every WRA, almost all ICs are grounded to the LRU chassis. Consequently any noise voltage felt on the fuselage will be felt on the ground plane of most ICs. Even very low (<5 VAC) are known to cause what is known as "electron migration" on the IC substrate.